# How IoC Container implements Dependency Injection compared to how I would implement it

Tags: .net, database-design, frameworks, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

To do Dependency Injection, I could create a generic dictionary of different types of db connections and then instantiate one type dynamically through reflection before passing it to the object's constructor that needs it.

What difference and benefit does it bring when using an IOC Container since It doesn't make my stuff more independant than the first solution. How the IOC Container would do internally ? Is it different from the first solution ?

How would you implement DI without container ? When would you switch to an IoC Container ?

I mean is there other way to implement DI other than the one I have thought about so that I could use the best way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose a container does a lot of the boiler-plate code for you.  For example, it does exactly what you said, instantiating a class based on the reflected behavior.  Many containers also allow you to explicitly configure your system based on config files.

IOC or DI are only concepts.  IOC/DI concepts give you the "indenpendency" that you favor.  The actual implementation can vary.  You can do it without using a third-party container -- or write your own.  Or you can leverage the features provided by a well-tested third-party container.

If you just want to inject different types of db connections, they you have a very small need for IOC/DI.  In general IOC/DI (beware, not the container, which is just an *implementation* of IOC/DI) gives you totally configurable software, aids in unit testing (by injecting stubs), self-configuration, etc.

Typically IOC/DI is necessary when:

1. your software is so large and complex that no single person has it all in his head, or
2. has so many different configurations that you don't want customized builds, or
3. is so inter-dependent among the pieces that you find it difficult to test each piece alone

Comment: Thanks that the kind of answer I wanted. Is there other way to implement DI other than the one I have thought about ?

Comment: Well, I believe different implementations will use different methods.  However, they should all be "class" or "interface" based.  They differ in how they instantiate certain classes or "auto-inject" into public properties of classes.  In general, they all do something like: 1) build a catalog of classes mapped to interfaces/base classes, like your dictionary, 2) instantiate the relevant class object and "inject", and if there are multiple possible choices, pick one based on certain rules -- which can be a config file or other rules.

Answer (score 3):

Dependency Injection has nothing to do with dictionaries. As Nicholas Blumhardt explains in an excellent blog post, you need a completely [different mental model for DI](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nblumhardt/archive/2008/12/27/container-managed-application-design-prelude-where-does-the-container-belong.aspx).

DI is loose coupling through the application of the **Constructor Injection** and **Composition Root** design patterns. When a DI Container enters the picture it does so via the [Register Resolve Release](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/09/29/TheRegisterResolveReleasePattern.aspx) pattern.

So if a class requires a db connection, it requests one through the constructor.

Comment: I didn't say that DI is dictionary ! I'm explaining HOW I would IMPLEMENT DI with Dictionary and Reflection to pass the dependency at runtime to the constructor.

Comment: You are not obliged to use an IOC Container to do DI that's my point and you seems to pretend that DI => IoC Container as you need Register Resolve Release to manage so called life cycle. This is implementation and I discuss between 2 implementations.

Comment: So I changed the title to make my question clearer that I'm talking about Implementation not about what is DI Concept.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing says you need to use an IoC container, it's just that IoC containers are pre-built, and you don't have to write the code yourself.  This means you can concentrate on building your app, and not your own DI system.

It's like building your UI or using a third party control.  Both work, it just depends on where you want to spend your time.  I know I don't really care much about building my own DI system, so I would rather use a pre-built one.

You might as well ask, why use a framework at all when you can write directly to the OS APIs.  It's all about improving reliability (by reusing code someone else has already written and spent lots of time making sure was bug free) and boosting your productivity (by not having to write everything yourself).

EDIT:

There are lots of ways to implement DI.  You could always look at all the containers that are out there, and how they work.  They're all open source, and the source code is available.

Comment: My question isn't about generality, it's about implementation. How IOC Container implements DI compared to how I could implement it ?

Comment: @user310291 - You're not being very clear in your question then, as I did not get that at all from your question. You seem to be asking if there is any technical reason to use one or the other. If that's not what you mean, then i suggest rewording your question.

Comment: ok i reformulate: "HOW IoC Container implements Dependency Injection compared to HOW I would implement it". So it's about HOW so that I can really choose myself :)

Comment: "You could always look at all the containers that are out there, and how they work." Well I don't want to because I just want to know the principles for I don't have time to study them all :)

Comment: Well then, if you don't have time to study then, why do you have time to build your own?

Comment: Because building my own gives me better understanding instead of doing cargo Cult programming